# Is there a Python module to access Advantage Database Server?

Tags: python, database, module, dbf, advantage-database-server

As the title suggest, I was wondering if there is a Python module that can access an Advantage Database Server (Sybase) files such as ADT and DBF.

I have searched the web and couldn't find what I'm looking for this is why I wanted to ask it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used pyodbc with the Advantage ODBC driver, http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/ and pywin32 http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/ with the Advantage OLE DB provider successfully.   My personal preference is the pyodbc driver.

There is now a native wrapper at http://code.google.com/p/adsdb/.

Answer (score 1):

[dbfpy](http://www.fiby.at/dbfpy/) (and many other modules) let you read and write DBF files. I'm not aware of similar modules dealing with ADT files directly, but I think there are converters to make DBF files to/from ADT, if worse comes to worst.

Another alternative for accessing ADT files would be to actually *run* sybase advantage with its [odbc](http://www.sybase.com/products/databasemanagement/advantagedatabaseserver/odbc-driver) driver -- if that is feasible, there are several ways to connect to an ODBC service with Python.

Comment: Thanks for this. Converting ADT to DBF wouldn't be an option for me. So I'll leave this question unanswered since it's only half answered.